# Svg Icon in expo react native appearing half or only a part of the icon

Tags: react-native, expo

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SvgXml } from 'react-native-svg';

export default function SvgComponent() {
  const svgcode = `<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="Iconly/Light-Outline/Profile">
  <g id="Profile">
  <g id="Group 3">
  <mask id="mask0_33437_4900" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="4" y="14" width="16" height="8">
  <path id="Clip 2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4 14.4961H19.8399V21.8701H4V14.4961Z" fill="white"/>
  </mask>
  <g mask="url(#mask0_33437_4900)">
  <path id="Fill 1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.9209 15.9961C7.65988 15.9961 5.49988 16.7281 5.49988 18.1731C5.49988 19.6311 7.65988 20.3701 11.9209 20.3701C16.1809 20.3701 18.3399 19.6381 18.3399 18.1931C18.3399 16.7351 16.1809 15.9961 11.9209 15.9961M11.9209 21.8701C9.96188 21.8701 3.99988 21.8701 3.99988 18.1731C3.99988 14.8771 8.52088 14.4961 11.9209 14.4961C13.8799 14.4961 19.8399 14.4961 19.8399 18.1931C19.8399 21.4891 15.3199 21.8701 11.9209 21.8701" fill="black"/>
  </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Group 6">
  <mask id="mask1_33437_4900" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="6" y="2" width="12" height="11">
  <path id="Clip 5" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M6.60986 2.00012H17.2299V12.6187H6.60986V2.00012Z" fill="white"/>
  </mask>
  <g mask="url(#mask1_33437_4900)">
  <path id="Fill 4" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.9209 3.42776C9.77989 3.42776 8.03789 5.16876 8.03789 7.30976C8.03089 9.44376 9.75989 11.1838 11.8919 11.1918L11.9209 11.9058V11.1918C14.0609 11.1918 15.8019 9.44976 15.8019 7.30976C15.8019 5.16876 14.0609 3.42776 11.9209 3.42776M11.9209 12.6188H11.8889C8.9669 12.6098 6.59989 10.2268 6.60989 7.30676C6.60989 4.38176 8.99189 1.99976 11.9209 1.99976C14.8489 1.99976 17.2299 4.38176 17.2299 7.30976C17.2299 10.2378 14.8489 12.6188 11.9209 12.6188" fill="black"/>
  </g>
  </g>
  </g>
  </g>
  </svg>
  `;
  const Svg = () => (
    <SvgXml
      xml={svgcode}
      width='set the width here'
      height='set the height here'
    />
  );

  return <Svg />;
}
```

I am importing this and using it but the icon is appearing half what's the issue? The SVG is appearing properly in the browser. I have searched a lot but no help. Also tell if there is any other way to use svg in expo app

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure but just a suggestion. Check if you have any other component getting rendered above your SVG.

Why I am guessing this is because since your phone is a relatively smaller device than your browser on a computer, any other component might get squashed thus forcing it to display above your SVG and you might be seeing it as if it's appearing half. On computer screens that might not be the case.

Let me know more about the issue so that I'm more clear about it.

Comment: i have tried a different svg and its working fine. But I want this svg in the project what the issue how I can find

Comment: Have you tried making the SVG very small by adjusting the width and height parameters? if it appears fully while it is very small, the problem is not with your SVG otherwise the SVG itself might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the mask property `style="mask-type:alpha"` is not supported in react native svg, see [this issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/issues/1790) for the react native svg, and also [this issue](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/336) in SVGR detailing the problem a lot better